# How to get a value from json data

Tags: json

I have a json data like,

```
{
    "attributes": {

    },
    "body": "title: \"store\"\n' + 'url: \"https://fffffff.com/crr\"\n' + 'adsense: ",
    "bodyBegin": 1
}
```

I need to get value `https://fffffff.com/crr"\n`

How to get it from this code?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is not valid, however,

```
{
   "attributes":{
      
   },
   "body":{
      "title":"store\n",
      "url":"https://fffffff.com/crr\n",
      "adsense":""
   },
   "bodyBegin":1
}
```

Editing it to be valid is simple, and getting the "url" keys value would simply be

```
jsondata.body.url
```

Comment: Thanks, but value of body is a single long string with `+` sign, not like yours

Comment: jsondata["body"].split("url: ",1)[1].split("' +", 1)[0] in python with the response you gave should work